# How can I print the header of a .csv file in Java with package org.apache.commons.csv?

Tags: java, csv

I use the following code to read a `.csv` file in Java. How can I print the *header* of the file using this code? (I use the packages `edu.duke` and `org.apache.commons.csv` from [here](http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/downloads/bluej.php?course=3).)

```
import edu.duke.*;
import org.apache.commons.csv.*;
import java.io.*;

public class myCSVParser {
    public static void readData() {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource("smauto2.csv");
        CSVParser ps = fr.getCSVParser();
        // ??
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
String fileName = "data.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName ));
```

// if the first line is the header

```
String[] header = reader.readNext();
```

OR

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.csv"));
    String header = br.readLine();
    if (header != null) {
        String[] columns = header.split(",");
    }
```